# Newbie, for GIS (need wander path, trail data)

Tags: shapefile, postgresql, openstreetmap, data, extract

I need Greek wander paths of places like mountains and forests as shapefiles, but I don't know how to start to extract them from specific sites or getting them ready as shapefiles. I need these data to store them in a Postgres DB and execute some PostGIS queries to find people who have been lost in a region. Can you give me some instructions how to extract these data or sites where I can find them ready?

I have found some sites where you can place your route like these here:
[wandermap](http://www.wandermap.net/en/?tab=new#/z13/38.9772646,22.0168591/terrain) or this [OSM specific](http://hikebikemap.org/), but I don't know how to extract the data as shapefiles. More specific, if it is possible I want to make a selection by dropping a rectangle over a region or country and extract these content as shapefiles. Is this possible?. And if yes, how can I achieve this?.

The data are needed to build something like this here: [Introduction to web programming for GIS applications](https://www.udemy.com/introduction-to-web-programming-for-gis-applications/)

Comment: Take the tour: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour. Your question is to broad.

Comment: Ok sorry, I will shorten it a little bit cause my main problem is to find such GIS data and convert them as shapefiles. Better or what do you mean?.

Comment: If you are looking for data you are maybe more likely to get an answer at Open Data Stack Exchange (https://opendata.stackexchange.com/). When you have the data, if it is not in shape format you can ask a new question here on how to convert it. There should only be one question per post, you have Three.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I will look after to find them first and then get back to ask for conversion.

Comment: You can download this data as a zip of shapefiles: https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/greece.html

Comment: I have downloaded them and want to import them in the Postgres DB using the UI PostGIS shapefile import Manager (windows) but I am getting an error: Shapefile import failed. I have created a DB in Postgres named gisdb and in the importer, I have marked all the shp files but it doesn't work :(. The SRID is set to 0 maybe this is the problem?.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not enough reputations to go to chat :(.

Comment: you don't need go in chat. With minor edits, I think you could post your previous comment as a new question. Just be clear on the things that have worked and the _one question you are asking._

Comment: Ok, I have fixed it myself cause there was no PostGIS extension created in my DB. Now I have imported the data and with QGIS I am able to see them graphically. The paths are not enough from OSM but I will search for them via the Open Data forum. Thanks again for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data from OSM can be extracted in a defined area from www.bbbike.org. here is the [link](https://extract.bbbike.org/)

Comment: Thank you, the site looks great but I can only extract 128MB and I need the whole greek map which costs a lot of money (99E/month) :(. Do you know maybe how I can extract data from here: http://hikebikemap.org/  or here http://www.wandermap.net